# Create a count daily variable with an additional condition

Tags: r

I have something like the following:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                   condition=c(0,1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,1), 
                   day=c(7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33)
                 )
```

I'm trying to count the number of 'daily's' given condition==1 per 'group'.

But, I also want to include the "dailys" right after condition==1 (even if the current row condition==0). So for example, group 1 "dailys" would be 3 (days 7, 8, 9), 2 (days 12 and 13), and 1 (day 15), but I ACTUALLY would want "dailys" 0 (for day 7 where condition==0), 2 (for days 8 and 9 where condition==1), 2 (for days 12 and 13 EVEN THOUGH condition==0 for day 13, I've tried lag/diff functions here), and 0 (for day 15 where condition==0).

So, when condition goes from 1->0 in the next row (AND it's the next day, NOT >=two days later) I want this to remain as part of the 'daily' count, but when condition goes from 0->1 in the next row I'd like the count to reset.

I would want a column to work with, something like the following (which might not be efficient), but other methods to return the max amount of 'dailys' per group is very welcome (group 1 has max "dailys" of 2, group 2 has max "dailys" of 3, group 3 has max dailys of 2):

```
#   group condition day intermediate want
#1      1         0   7            0    0
#2      1         1   8            1    2
#3      1         1   9            2    2
#4      1         1  12            1    2
#5      1         0  13            2    2
#6      1         0  15            0    0
#7      2         0  16            0    0
#8      2         1  17            1    3
#9      2         1  18            2    3
#10     2         1  19            3    3
#11     2         1  21            1    2
#12     2         1  22            2    2
#13     3         1  23            1    1
#14     3         1  28            1    2
#15     3         0  29            2    2
#16     3         1  31            1    2
#17     3         0  32            2    2
#18     3         1  33            1    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think intermediate step is missing between input data and `want`. I cannot figure out the logic. Specifically, it is not clear why days 18-19 have value of 3.

Comment: Maybe this will help: 
```dfwant<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
               condition=c(0,1,1,1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,1), 
               day=c(7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33),
               intermediate=c(0,1,2,1,2,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1 ),
               want=c(0, 2,2, 2,2,0, 0, 3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1) 
               )
```

Comment: 17, 18 and 19 are '3' because they are consecutive (daily), are all in group 2 and have condition==1. Apologies if it is unclear.

Comment: For clarity, can you please update the question so the days in your example there match the days in your example output & `dfwant` from your question? e.g. should row 13 be 27 or 23?

Comment: Sorry! will update stand by

Comment: Why day `21` has intermediate of `1`, not say 4?

Comment: Because it is two days after 19 so I want the count to reset to 1 (i.e. it is not daily). As part of group 2, days 21 and 22 are consecutive (daily), so intermediate starts the count at 1 (21) then 2 (22). If day 23 belonged to group 2, intermediate would have been 1, 2, 3

Comment: if day 21 was 20 then yes intermediate would be 4

Comment: Ok, I think it will be better to get this to a data.frame with all days first (which probably the first problem you need to solve). After that application of `shift` will make more sense